# SSRS Treemap Label Text Properties

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, treemap

I created a **treemap** in SSRS.

I am using the **Series Label** to display text in the box in the lower left corner.

I am also displaying other text in the upper left corner with the **Label** property of the **Series Group**.

The properties of the **Series Label** seem to control the **Series Group label** in the top except for the Weight - it's always Bold and looks blocky.

Are there any properties for the **Series Group Label**? How do I get rid of the Bold in the font?

[image]